# How to calculate Employee Weekly OFF in a month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I wrote funtion for this which is working fine but there is one issue if employee joining mid of month or last week so how to count his/her weekly holidays.

**Currently below function getting his/her all Holidays in a month.**

```
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetTotalWeekHoliday]    Script Date: 1/23/2024 12:12:04 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTotalWeekHoliday]
    (
        @Month AS nvarchar(10), -- parameter a
        @date AS date, -- parameter b
        @count1 AS INT,
        @HolidayName AS nvarchar(50),
        @year AS nvarchar(10)
    )
    RETURNS INT -- return type
    AS
    BEGIN
    set @date=@year+'-'+@Month+'-'+'01'
    while DATEPART(Month,@date)=@Month
Begin
    --Select DATEPART(DAY,@date);
    --Select DATEPART( WEEKDAY, @DATE )
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(20)

    SELECT  @Name = CASE ( DATEPART(dw, @Date) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7
                         WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
                         WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
                         WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
                         WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
                         WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
                         WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
                         WHEN 0 THEN 'Saturday'
                       END 
    If @Name=@HolidayName
    Begin
        
        --Insert Data Into Your Table
        set @count1+=1
    End
    
    Set @date=DATEADD(Day,1,@date); 
End
        RETURN @count1 -- return statement
    END;
```

> Example
> Current month
> employee1  holiday name ='Tuesday'
> result will be "5"
> but if employee1 appointed 20th january
> then i want to show result "2"
> currently its showing all "5"

Comment: IMHO you should not use SQL to calculate anything. SQL should be purely used to CRUD in and from databases. Calculations should be done with programming language either frontend or backend depending on the security concerns. Also note, that a calculation answer depends on the local laws. Some countries strictly count a month by 30 days. It then also depends on the working days and the working days per week.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. You can't expect us to reverse engineer your code and fix it.

Comment: @tacoshy totally disagree, data calculation can often be done far more efficiently and with better performance in the database. (Not the way OP has done though - set-based).

Comment: I get your point but I believe that either pipelines are more effective or in this specific case you have to work with the data on request. A normal HR employee needs the data displayed and changeable with a GUI. SO you can outsource the computing to the user's PC and save overall performance. But I'm willing to admit that it always depends on the infrastructure and the size of the company. Also their general approaches of concepts

Comment: I won't bother trying to improve the function, but it looks like you can fix it with changing: `set @date=@year+'-'+@Month+'-'+'01'`to `set @date=@year+'-'+@Month+'-'+RIGHT('0', CAST(DATEPART(DAY, @date) as varchar(2)), 2)`

Comment: If you haven't already, build yourself a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) they are very useful. With the example in the article you can a avoid loops completely and use a simple count: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Calendar AS c WHERE c.TheDayName = @Holiday AND c.TheMonth = @Month AND c.TheYear = @Year AND c.TheDate >= @EmployeeStartDate`.

Comment: As an aside, why on earth would you use `nvarchar(10)` as the data type for `@year` and `@month`? The former can never be anything other than a number, and the latter is expected to be a number (based on `DATEPART(MONTH, @Date) = @month` so by allowing 10 non-unicode characters you are opening yourself up for problems

Answer (score -1, accepted):

function for employees joining mid-month I added a new parameter `@JoiningDate, to specify their start date. The function's loop now includes a check to ensure it only counts holidays that fall on or after this joining date. Additionally, the function internally determines the first day of the given month

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTotalWeekHoliday]
(
    ...
    @JoiningDate AS date  -- New parameter for employee's joining date
    ...
)
...
BEGIN
    ...
    while DATEPART(Month, @date) = CONVERT(int, @Month) AND @date <= EOMONTH(@date)
    BEGIN
        ...
        -- Check if the date is a holiday and is on or after the joining date
        IF @DayName = @HolidayName AND @date >= @JoiningDate
        BEGIN
            set @count1 += 1
        END
        ...
    END
    ...
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment, I would highly recommend that you build yourself a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). They are very useful, and pretty much the first thing I add to any database I build. With one in place your query becomes a simple count:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    dbo.Calendar AS c
WHERE   c.TheDayName = @Holiday
AND     c.TheMonth = @Month
AND     c.TheYear = @Year
AND     c.TheDate >= @EmployeeStartDate;
```

If you can't/won't do that, then the next best thing is to generate a list of dates yourself (without a loop), then you can filter that and count the days that meet your criteria, e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTotalWeekHoliday
    (
        @year SMALLINT,
        @Month TINYINT,
        @joindate DATE,
        @DayName VARCHAR(10)
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(   WITH Dates AS
    (   SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n1.N) - 1, ms.MonthStart),ms.MonthStart      
        FROM    (VALUES (DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1))) AS ms (MonthStart)
        -- Cross join to 8x4 rows (32) to ensure full month
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS n1 (N)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS n2 (N)
    )
    SELECT  Holidays = COUNT(*)
    FROM    Dates AS d
    WHERE   DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d.Date) = @DayName
    AND     d.Date >=ISNULL(@JoinDate, '19000101')
    AND     d.Date < EOMONTH(d.MonthStart)
);
```

Note I've converted this to a TVF as this is not inlinable as a scalar UDF, so this will be more efficient when used. An example use of this would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES 
  (1, 2024, '20231223'), 
  (1, 2024, '20240120')
  ) as d (Month, Year, StartDate)
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetTotalWeekHoliday(d.Year, d.Month, d.StartDate,'Tuesday') AS h;
```

But if you need to call like a scalar function for any reason you can do so as follows:

```
SELECT *,
   Holidays = (SELECT h.Holidays FROM dbo.GetTotalWeekHoliday(d.Year, d.Month, d.StartDate,'Tuesday') AS h)
FROM (VALUES 
  (1, 2024, '20231223'), 
  (1, 2024, '20240120')
  ) as d (Month, Year, StartDate);
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uOg_cfGH)**